# WSL2にChromeをインストールしたのにWindows側が起動されてしまう

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, google-chrome, wsl-2

**概要**
WindowsでWSL2を有効化し、UbuntuにChromeをインストールして、bashのコマンドラインで起動すると、以前はUbuntu版のChromeが起動していたが、ある日急にWindows版が起動されるようになってしまった。Ubuntu版が起動するように戻したい。

**詳細**
Windows 10において、WSL2を有効化し、Ubuntu 20.04をインストールしました。
目的はPython3+Selenium＋ChromeDriverを使って、Chromeブラウザーを自動化することです。

XサーバーとしてVcXsrvをインストールし、設定しました。
xeyesおよびEmacsは正常に動作しているので、ここまでに問題はないと思います。

次に、以下のコマンドによって、UbuntuにChromeをインストールしました。

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list' # 供給元を追加する
$ sudo wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add - # 公開鍵を追加する
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install google-chrome-stable
```

次に、Chromeを起動しました。

```
$ google-chrome&
```

これで、最初のうちは、Ubuntu側のChromeが起動していました。

しかし、ある日急に、同じコマンドでWindowsのChromeが起動してしまうようになりました。

```
$ google-chrome
```

とフォアグラウンド実行しても$プロンプトが表示され、`ps`コマンドを入力してもgoogle-chromeプロセスが見えません。（以前Ubuntu側のChromeが実行できていたときは見えていました）

```
$ which google-chrome
```

で`/home/user_name/bin/google-chrome`と返るので、フルパスを指定して

```
$ /home/user_name/bin/google-chrome
```

と書いて起動しても同じ結果になります。

関係あるかどうか分かりませんが、WindowsのChromeをすべて閉じても、Windowsのタスクマネージャーでプロセスを見ると「Google Chrome」というプロセスが11個走っています。これが問題かと思いすべて右クリックしてプロセスを殺して、再度Ubuntuで

```
$ /home/user_name/bin/google-chrome
```

と書いても同じ結果になります。

Windowsを再起動して、まったくChromeを起動しない状態でも、Windowsのタスクマネージャーでプロセスを見ると「Google Chrome」というプロセスが11個走っています。この時点で

```
$ /home/user_name/bin/google-chrome
```

と書いても同じ結果になります。

Windowsを再起動して、まったくChromeを起動しない状態で、タスクマネージャーを開いて「Google Chrome」というプロセスをすべて右クリックしてプロセスを殺して、再度Ubuntuで

```
$ /home/user_name/bin/google-chrome
```

と書いても同じ結果になります。

SeleniumはFirefoxもサポートしているので、Chromeを使わなければいいような気がしますが、Google Driveなどのサービスと連携するワークフローを設計している関係で、出来ればChromeを使いたい状態です。

元のようにUbuntu側のChromeを起動するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: これ [相互運用性の無効化](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/interop#disable-interoperability) かそのページ内のどれか、またはこれ [WSL2でWindowsのPATH設定が引き継がれるのを解除する](https://zenn.dev/o2z/articles/zenn-20210524-01) あたりかもしれませんね。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
いただいたコメントがキッカケで真相が分かりました。
で、完全に私の勘違いでした。
一応自己回答しますが、こういう場合どうすればいいか分かりません。。
いずれにしても助かりました。

Comment: 自己回答で問題無いと思いますよ。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問者自己回答です。
いただいたコメントをきっかけに真相に到達しましたが、もとの問題は完全に私の失敗でした。
（質問ごと消したほうがいいか、バカ事例として残すのも意味があるのか思案中です。ご教示賜れば幸いです）

**まとめ**
結論としては、`/home/user_name/bin/google-chrome`という名前で、以下のようなシェルスクリプトを作っていました。

```
#! /bin/sh

exec /mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe "$@"
```

こちらは、WSL1を使っていた頃に、Windows版のChromeを起動するために、わざわざ置いていたものでした。

質問の中で書いた`apt install`でインストールされたUbuntu版の実体は`/usr/bin/google-chrome`にありますが、`/home/user_name/bin`の方が`PATH`に先に入っていたので優先実行されていました。

**判明までの過程**
どうやって分かったかは以下の通りです。

WSL2のUbuntuからWindowsのexeファイルを実行するのはWSL2の相互運用性という機能を使います。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/wsl/interop#disable-interoperability

これを無効化してみました。

上記のドキュメントによると以下のコマンドをsuとして実行します。

```
# echo 0 > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop
```

こちらは、一般ユーザーとしてログインした状態で`sudo`を使っても「/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInteropの権限がありません」と言われ、`su`でスーパーユーザーとしてログインしないと操作できません。

Ubuntuでは、デフォルトでrootユーザーのパスワードが設定されていないので、以下の操作を行います（xxxxxは任意のパスワード）。

```
$ sudo su -
# passwd
Enter new UNIX password: xxxxx
Retype new UNIX password: xxxxx
passwd: password updated successfully
```

そして以下のようにsuとしてログインして以下の操作を行います。

```
$ su
Password: 
# echo 0 > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/WSLInterop
# exit
```

これで、Windows版のChromeをUbuntu側から実行できなくなりました。
この状態でもう一度google-chromeを起動してみました。
エラーが発生します。

```
$ /home/user_name/bin/google-chrome: 3: exec: /mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe: Exec format error

[1]+  終了 2                /home/user_name/bin/google-chrome
```

これで、さすがの私も、`/home/user_name/bin/google-chrome`はシェルスクリプトであると分かったので変名し、改めてgoogle-chromeの場所を探しました。

```
$ which google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

で、`/usr/bin/google-chrome`を改めて起動すると、ちゃんとUbuntu版のChromeが起動しました。

以上です。すみませんでした。